# Как перехватить отправку формы

Tags: jquery, ajax

Есть страница, и на этой странице данные загружаются из другого файла с помощью ajax. Так вот как из загружаемых данных перехватить отправку с помощью jquery. Если убрать ajax и сделать все на одной странице, то jquery перехватывает отправку формы.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('form').click(function(){
        var formID = $(this).attr('id');  // Получение ID формы
        var formNm = $('#' + formID);
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'config/prop',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: formNm.serialize(),
    traditional: true,
    success:function(data){
var response = JSON.parse(data);
if(response.buy){
    $("#result").fadeIn(500);
} else if (response.profit) {
    $("#toast-container").fadeIn(500);
    $("#result").html(response.profit);
    setTimeout(function() {
$('#toast-container').fadeOut('fast')},7000); //10000 = 10 секунд 
} 
  else 
     alert('hddgh');
},
   error: function(response) {
alert('huevo');
}
});
return false;   
})

});
setInterval(function () {
$("#prop").load("ajax/prop #aprop");
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если под "перехватить отправку формы" вы подразумеваете "повесить свой обработчик на сабмит формы", то вам следует вешать обработчик либо после добавления формы на станицу, либо вешать обработчик на контейнер, в который вы форму вставляете.

Вот как это делается

```js
// сперва формы нет и мы вешаем обработчик на контйнер (который уже присутствует)
$('#formWrapper').on('submit', 'form', function(e) { // обратите внимание как вешается событие
  e.preventDefault(); // выключаем поведение по умолчанию (обычную отправку формы)
  var formData = new FormData(this);
  var $output = $('#output');
  $output.empty();
  for (var value of formData.values()) {
    var $line = $('<p />');
    $line.text(value);
    $output.append($line);
  }
});

// типа загрузили форму с какого-нибудь урла
// вставляем её в документ
$('#formWrapper').html('<form><input name="foo" type="text"><button type="submit">Submit</button></form>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="formWrapper">loading...</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо разобрался. Вставлять форму не нужно было, нужно было получить данные из нее!

Comment: @Артём ну `load` вставляет то, что загрузил. А для примера я просто вставил html. Надеюсь вы ухватили главное -- вешать обработчики событий можно только на те элементы, которые уже присутствуют на странице.